# Having issues connected with chrome.storage.sync.set property and also it causes problems connected with chrome extension creation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Actually, I have a task, where I should just create chrome extension, which will pop up and give me access to download images. Here I try to do that, however I am facing a problem, first in code and then in the chrome account. Code says me that Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync').
I just wrote `chrome.storage.sync.set`, but as far as I understood it cannot read that. what to do here ?

and the rest is connected with chrome extension creation, because I want to do the exact thing, which is here https://techblog.geekyants.com/building-a-chrome-extension-in-2021#heading-step-1-setting-up-the-initial-project, but in final time, I am facing some problems. How to put it on the chrome.

[this is chrome problem, who to do here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJPUU.png)

[and this is the code problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajUCQ.png)

Comment: Assuming your manifest.json has "storage" in "permissions" the problem is that you open extension pages from a web server (127.0.0.1). This is wrong. You need to open them by installing the extension first, then opening the relevant UI e.g. click the icon to open the popup or right-click the icon and choose Options.

Comment: how to i download that?